# Display book details from mysql-php

Tags: php, mysql

I really need help.

My problem now is i want to display the books details, which the data is from mysql.

I tell step-by-step.

1. i have table books in mysql
2. from the table, i called the title and price using php, which display like this :

Title : One
Price : 20$

---

Title : Two
Price : 35$

---

my php code is :

```
<?php

$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_pass="";
$db_name="";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die("Could not connect to database.");

@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("No database");


$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books ");

while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $q )) 
 {

 echo "<b>Title:</b> ".$result['title'] . " <br> ";
 echo "<b>Price:</b> RM".$result['price_myr'] ."<br>"; 
 echo "<br>";

 }

?>
```

1. Here the problem start. I want to display the book details ( author, publisher, descrp, etc...) when user click on the list above ( step 2) . So can anyone give me the idea on how can i do that ?  How to make the book list available for click and then it display the details.

example :

User click on listview ; Title:One ,
the details about the book popup or load.

I guess i need to use Ajax, but i dont know how.

Hope members here can help. Much thanks !

Comment: You can either have all of the information already pulled before displaying the page and just unhide the information when clicked on, or you can use AJAX to pull that information when they click on it.

Comment: @Michael I dont know how to accept... I tried to vote but cant since its required 15reputation.

Comment: There is a blank looking check mark right below voting, click that and it will accept the answer (by turning the check mark into a green checkmark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap each book in `<div>` tags, and create an `onclick` function for each one.

Whether it has the information pre-loaded or fetches the information on-demand is up to you. If you have a ton of books listed on the page, pre-loading the information might cause performance issues, so it may be better to load the book information on-demand, via AJAX.

Here is what your code might look like, using AJAX:

```
// styling should be done in a CSS file, but for the simplicity of the example, including it inline
echo "<div id=\"divBookInfo\" style=\"display:none; position:fixed; bottom:0; right:0;\">
    </div>\n";

$q = mysql_query("SELECT title, price_myr FROM books");

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
    echo "<div onclick=\"showBookInfo({$result["bookID"]})\">
            <b>Title:</b> {$result["title"]} <br />
            <b>Price:</b> {$result["price_myr"]} <br />
        </div>\n";
}
```

And your JavaScript function:

```
function showBookInfo(bookID)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("divBookInfo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("divBookInfo").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getBookInfo.php?bookID="+ bookID, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**getBookInfo.php:**

```
<?php

$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_pass="";
$db_name="";

@mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass) or die("Could not connect to database.");

@mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("No database");

$q = mysql_query("SELECT author, publisher, description, ... FROM books WHERE bookID = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["bookID"]) ."'");

list($author, $publisher, $description, ...) = mysql_fetch_row($q);

echo "<b>Author:</b> {$author} <br />
    <b>Publisher:</b> {$publisher} <br />
    <b>Description:</b> {$description} <br />";
?>
```

**ALSO**

One other side-note is that you should avoid the use of the `or die()` syntax in a PHP script that is generating your HTML. See [this link](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) for some reasons why.

Comment: Thanks @Travesty3 . I tried your code too, but I got the problem as code given by Michael. The javascript seems like did not work. Maybe there's some problem with the link which make the js cant be read.

Comment: @haura: You need to create the script that you are calling via AJAX. In my example, I called it getBookInfo.php. See my updated answer for an example of what that might look like. And you really should read a [tutorial on AJAX](http://w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp). It is incredibly useful and you will undoubtedly need it again in the future.

Comment: The div=onClick works now ! but getBookInfo.php got this error .  

"  Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in "

Comment: @haura: You will need to modify the MySQL query to select the columns you need. I put in a ... in the places where you need to change for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familar with jQuery there are 2 easy ways to accomplish it!  There is the Ajax version (cooler, but more complicated) and the simple show/hide.

`1.` In your mysql statement, make sure you have all the details you want to display.  Create a surrounding tag that can be css selected like so.

```
//From your code
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $q )) 
{
    echo "<div id='book-{$result['id']}'class='book-info'>
        echo "<b>Title:</b> ".$result['title'] . " <br> ";
        echo "<b>Price:</b> RM".$result['price_myr'] ."<br>"; 
        echo "<div class='book-details'>
            echo "here is some details<br/>"; 
            echo "here is more details"; 
        echo "</div>" 
    echo "</div>"
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Now in the javascript do this

```
$(".book-info").click(function() {
    $(".book-details", $(this)).toggle();
})
```

and of course, make the book details start hidden.

```
<style>
    .book-details{display:none}
</style>
```

Comment: You can do this with ajax, but i will let you explore that.  You would just have to do some easy fetching and displaying in a different file.  Here is what toggle means http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: [Suggesting switching to jQuery just to toggle show/hide?](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: @Travesty3 thats not very constructive.  He asked how can he show / hide text based on a click.  I am offering a solution that is easy for a new person to begin.  And if he tries to use ajax, am i being so far off?  I do not think so.  I am not suggesting switching to jQuery, i am just offering a solution in jQuery that is simple to code and i think simple to understand.

Comment: Sorry if I offended you...I find a lot of people suggesting jQuery to do the simplest tasks, and I find that link to be humorous, so I shared it on what I see as a fitting answer. It wasn't meant to be constructive, aside from avoiding overcomplicating a trivial task.

Comment: @Michael I tried your code, the css works but the javascript i'm not sure since I still cannot click to display the details.

Comment: Your code got syntax error .


echo "<div id='book-{$result['id']}'class='book-info'>
        echo "<b>Title:</b> ".$result['title'] . " <br> ";
        echo "<b>Price:</b> RM".$result['price_myr'] ."<br>"; 
        echo "<div class='book-details'>
            echo "here is some details<br/>"; 
            echo "here is more details"; 
        echo "</div>" 
    echo "</div>"
    echo "<br>";

Comment: I edit the code till no syntax error but really sure I make it didnt works. =.=

Comment: @haura You must not have jquery.  If you are not familiar with jQuery then you will need to know some of the functions work and how css selector works in jQuery.